# Calculating time efficiency of a chunk of code

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have this chunk of code:

```
int f = 0;

for(int i=1 ; i<m ; i=i*2) {
    for(int l=500 ; l<700 ; l++) {
        f++;
    }
    for(int j=n ; j>0 ; j=j/2) {
        f++;
    }
    for(int k=0 ; k<m ; k=k+3) {
        f++;
    }

    f += 10;
}
```

where m and n are given as parameters.

So far I have calculated this:

the main for cycle increments exponentially, that means that its time efficiency is `O(log m)`

the first for cycle consumes constant time `O(200)`, so it does not affect the time efficiency of the code.

the second for cycle decrements by 1/2 of the value that has n every itteration, therefore its time efficiency is `O(log n)`

the third for cycle increments by 3 every itteration => it has `O(m/3)` time efficiency, but we don't need a constant, so it is `O(m)`

All in all, when we combine everything we get `O(log(m) * (log n + m))`.

Is this analysis all correct?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young n and m are parameters and therefore you can't simplify further as you're suggesting. The definition of big-O for two variables is "the run-time is O(f(n, m)) if there exists M, N, C, such that for all m>M, for all n>N, the run-time <= C.f(n, m)".

Comment: @anonymous Makes sense. In that case, the OP's analysis seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you may methodically find:

[image]